# MKMapView Select Annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I'm new to swift and currently trying to figure out how to get data about the annotation that the user has selected. I have a localsearch function that will add the annotations, and after the user selects one I'd like to be able to access that. I'm trying to use selectedAnnotations, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Localsearch:

```
func performSearch(){
    matchingItems.removeAll()
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchTextField.text
    request.region = mapView.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

    search.startWithCompletionHandler({(response:
        MKLocalSearchResponse!,
        error: NSError!) in

        if error != nil {
            println("Error occured in search: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else if response.mapItems.count == 0 {
            println("No matches found")
        } else {
            println("Matches found")

            for item in response.mapItems as [MKMapItem] {
                println("Name = \(item.name)")
                println("Phone = \(item.phoneNumber)")

                self.matchingItems.append(item as MKMapItem)
                println("Matching items = \(self.matchingItems.count)")

                var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = item.name
                annotation.subtitle = item.placemark.title
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

            }
        }
    })
```

From there I'm trying to use

```
 var selectedAnnotations: [MKPointAnnotation]!
        // print signout location
        println(selectedAnnotations)
```

To access the annotation, but this is just returning "nil"

Method for annotation:

```
    @IBAction func signoutToLocationButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    // saves current user location
    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
        (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // do something with the new geoPoint
            println(geoPoint)

            var signoutLocation = PFObject(className: "SignoutLocation")
            signoutLocation["Location"] = geoPoint
            signoutLocation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (success: Bool, error: NSError!)-> Void in
                if (success) {
                    // has been saved
                }
                else {
                    //went wrong
                }
            }

        }

        // get location of where they are signing out to
        self.mapView.selectedAnnotations(AnyObject)
        // print signout location
       //  println(selectedAnnotations)





    }
```

Comment: Your code is creating a local variable named "selectedAnnotations" which is an empty array.  You probably meant to access the map view's selectedAnnotations property (eg. `self.mapView.selectedAnnotations`).  Also: what method are you checking the selection in?

Comment: A different method that is called when the user selects a button. Would you like me to post that method too?

Comment: Try updating the code to use `self.mapView.selectedAnnotations` and post the method if still a problem.  If the button is on the annotation's callout, an easier way is to use the calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method.

Comment: The button isn't on the annotations callout. But okay, i'll try that. Thank you!

Comment: It's now telling me that "(AnyObject).Protocol -> $T3' is not identical to '[AnyObject]'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use the `selectedAnnotations` property:

```
if self.mapView.selectedAnnotations?.count > 0 {

    if let ann = self.mapView.selectedAnnotations[0] as? MKAnnotation {

        println("selected annotation: \(ann.title!)")

        let c = ann.coordinate
        println("coordinate: \(c.latitude), \(c.longitude)")

        //do something else with ann...
    }
}
```

(Though whether you need to or want to do this inside your `// has been saved` block instead of outside is something you'll have to figure out.)

Comment: Thank you, I'm able to get the annotation I want to be returned, but it's displaying it like this: "MKPointAnnotation: 0x170a47dd0", how can I get the lat/long off of the annotation data?

Comment: Getting the data out is similar to how the data was set when you created the annotation.  Added an example of getting the coordinate to the answer.